# Add Lodash to VS2015 Angular2 Project

Tags: angular, npm, lodash

I'm trying to add a dependency to lodash to my project but the VS2015 build keeps blowing up.  With this in the build output "Build: Cannot find module 'lodash'".  The build fails because the typescript compiler can't resolve lodash.  Here is my package.json dependancies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
```

Here is my system.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'Scripts/npmlibs/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'Scripts/npmlibs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'Scripts/npmlibs/rxjs',
        'lodash': 'Scripts/npmlibs/lodash/lodash.js'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'lodash': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade',
      'forms'
    ];

    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    }
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Most of the googling around this error has lead me to delete my node_modules folder completely and re run npm install.  I've done this 3 times, restarted VS2015, and restarted my VM but nothing fixes this.  I copy all the needed dependencies from /node_modules to /Scripts/npmlibs so that i don't have to deploy the 20k files npm downloads to our deployment web servers.  I have verified the paths in the system.config.js file.

I'm at a loss for what is wrong with VS/npm for why my build is failing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like lodash doesn't come with .d.ts files, or maybe i was installing it improperly through npm...  Either way to resolve this and get my typescript to compile i had to add this nuget package to my web project

[lodash type definitions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/lodash.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/2.3.7)

Which added /Scripts/typings/lodash/lodash-3.10.d.ts and lodash.d.ts.  I had to delete one because the TSC was complaining about duplicate definitions, so I deleted lodash-3.10.d.ts.  Restarted VS and it compiles.

I love angular2 so far but holy cow the JS/Typescript world is changing fast, I pine for the good old days of script src tags on your page, and downloading zip files with .js files... :(